# how to monitor all file changes in windows using bios interrupts in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to monitor all file changes in windows using BIOS interrupts in c++ but don't know how to do that.Can someone help me with that?
I tried Windows API but that's not able to monitor all file changes in windows.It just monitors file changes in a special directory.

Comment: This is like trying to build a suspension bridge out of cotton. You probably need a file system filter driver, but it's hard to tell because your question is vague.

Comment: Windows doesn't use the BIOS. You will need to use the Windows API for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449397/minifilter-vs-api-hooking-for-file-system-operations-monitoring-filtering

Answer (score 0):

In Windows it is not really practical to monitor hard drive changes in interrupt level because the Windows core takes care of it and it is not open.

You can alternatively monitor all processes and their changes to the hard drive. Take a look at: http://yaprocmon.sourceforge.net/ Its open source so you can try to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows sends notification about file changes using native API. And it does not necessarily use the BIOS.

Give a look to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I want it to be done using BIOS interrupts.

Comment: The point is that windows doesn't use BIOS interrupts. After it boots, it replaces the BIOS with its own drivers. Whether, they use or not internally the BIOS depends on the hardware manufacturer and / or driver developer. If you trap the BIOS you'll see... nothing.